# Stop Others Sound if any one playing from other cells when UIButton is press from uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9

When I pressed on `UIButton` Music starts. And when I again press on button music will stop. During playing music if I press on another cell button both music plays. I didn't understand how I can stop music that is playing from other cells or in other words only one music instance playing at once. Also a button image animation automatically set to its default state like `sender.selected = false`

Please can anyone tell me how i can do this?

Thanks

[UIButton connected with CollectionViewCell Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ufo5d.png)

[Default image State And when i pressed on button on different cells each cell play music and and change its image state to play](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SHBV.png)

```
class RadioCollectionViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    let reuseIdentifier = "cell" 

    var objects = [
        ["url" : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/kargopolov/BlueCafe.mp3", "image": "1.jpg"],
        ["url" : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/kargopolov/BlueCafe.mp3", "image": "2.jpg"],
        ["url" : "http://2016.downloadming1.com/bollywood%20mp3/Sanam%20Teri%20Kasam%20(2016)/02%20-%20Kheech%20Meri%20Photo%20-%20DownloadMing.SE.mp3", "image": "3.jpg"],
        ["url" : "http://2016.downloadming1.com/bollywood%20mp3/Sanam%20Teri%20Kasam%20(2016)/03%20-%20Bewajah%20-%20DownloadMing.SE.mp3", "image": "4.jpg"],
        ["url" : "http://2016.downloadming1.com/bollywood%20mp3/Sanam%20Teri%20Kasam%20(2016)/04%20-%20Tera%20Chehra%20-%20DownloadMing.SE.mp3", "image": "5.jpg"],
        ["url" : "http://2016.downloadming1.com/bollywood%20mp3/Sanam%20Teri%20Kasam%20(2016)/02%20-%20Kheech%20Meri%20Photo%20-%20DownloadMing.SE.mp3", "image": "6.jpg"],
        ["url" : "http://media.downloadming.se/TEMP/Loveshhuda%20(2015)/01%20-%20Mar%20Jaayen%20-%20DownloadMing.SE.mp3", "image": "5.jpg"],
        ["url" : "http://2016.downloadming1.com/bollywood%20mp3/Sanam%20Teri%20Kasam%20(2016)/01%20-%20Sanam%20Teri%20Kasam%20-%20DownloadMing.SE.mp3", "image": "7.jpg"],
        ["url" : "http://2016.downloadming1.com/bollywood%20mp3/Sanam%20Teri%20Kasam%20(2016)/02%20-%20Kheech%20Meri%20Photo%20-%20DownloadMing.SE.mp3", "image": "1.jpg"]]

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.objects.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RadioCollectionViewCell

        let object = objects[indexPath.row]
        cell.url = object["url"]! 
        cell.img.image = UIImage(named: object["image"]!)
        return cell
    }
}
```

In my `UICollectionViewCell` Class

```
class RadioCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView!

    var url : String!

    var playerItem:AVPlayerItem?
    var player:AVPlayer?

    @IBAction func audioControlButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {

        let nurl = NSURL(string: "\(url)")!
        playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: nurl)
        player=AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem!)

        if sender.selected == false {

            player!.play()
            sender.selected = true

        }else

        {
            player?.pause()
            sender.selected = false
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't check every time audio is playing or not. Simply call  `player.pause()` then start audio playing with `player.play()`

Comment: But when i pressed on more then one cells they all starts playing music at the same time. I want at a time one cell play music and i want if i pressed on another cell previously pressed cell music will automatically stop and play currently cell music, like this player [https://github.com/marshluca/AudioPlayer]
This is my project https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B29ka7gbDAYxSkNTdENabzB6UDA/view

Comment: @ZAFAR007 here is working code. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7pt8RzeP7M-UElLZGdSaFlOVWM

Comment: Thank you very much, You solved my problem In few minuts :-)

Comment: Can you please tell me one more thing? :D
How i can set last selected button animation to its default state when another cell button pressed, Like last selected button set it to default state "sender.selected = false"
You can see actual problem in this screenshot https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B29ka7gbDAYxV2lKVTNJRTBfUTA

Comment: Can you please check that problem?

Comment: @ZAFAR007 in few days i'm also going to do same thing will post your answer after i will done with this thing

Answer (score 0):

don't initiallize player in `RadioCollectionViewCell`, It will create multiple instance of your player. so, initialize player in viewcontroller in `viewDidLoad` only once and use this same player to play music with different url from different cell. so your cell should have only URl(different url for different music) and implement **`didSelectItemAtIndexPath`** method and pass url to common player from this method and play from this method.

**Update as ask in comment :**

for example,

```
   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

var cell : UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.magentaColor()
 }
```

here you can initialize player with url. this method is get called when cell is selected. so initialize player on cell's click and If you have `array of url` then you can get particular url by indexPath. so initialize player and play from this method.

**Edit:**

If you are using button in cell to play and pause then don't implement above code.

I found that you are creating new player in your `IBaction`. use same player. you can use one standard player declared as publicly. don't create new in ibaction. Take public instance of `avplayer` and use same for play music. that's it.
hope this will help :)

Comment: Can you please explain little bit how i can implement in didSelectItemAtIndexPath, i have tried but did't know properly implementation?

Comment: check my update. here what you doing wrong you have unique player for unique cell. if you use only one player and make that player `nil` first in button's click and then initialize with new url

Comment: Thanks for helping me :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting rate by default to 0.0 and assign 1.0 only when you play.

```
@IBAction func audioControlButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {

    let nurl = NSURL(string: "\(url)")!
    playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: nurl)
    player=AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem!)
    player.rate = 0.0
    if sender.selected == false {
        player.rate = 1.0
        player!.play()
        sender.selected = true
    }else{
        player?.pause()
        sender.selected = false
    }   
}
```

or you can set rate in didSelect method by default 0.0 and then assign 1.0 only when you play the sound file.

Hope this works !

Comment: But when i pressed on more then one cells they all starts playing music at the same time. I want at a time one cell play music and i want if i pressed on another cell previously pressed cell music will automatically stop and play currently cell music, like this player [github.com/marshluca/AudioPlayer] This is my project [drive.google.com/open?id=0B29ka7gbDAYxSkNTdENabzB6UDA]
Can you please check it

Comment: Hi looks like your issue is resolved....get the updated codebase here    https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7UCVsrOca0vSmgwS3BMa3ItM28 .. there was a mistake you were handling the play btn action from tableviewcell class.so each time it was creating independent instance of player....always cell's button action you should handle from controller thats what i did...and also playeritem is not required here..player item we use usually when we play a playlist.

Comment: Thanks but when i pressed on button music start playing and when i stopped it by pressing again it stopped and after few seconds it automatically again start playing.